# Does anyone have good idea to deploy a complex distributed system?

Tags: deployment

we have a web system, consist of 30 components like cache, DB, web, file store etc,
everyone have self configuration file, and depend on each other.

Does anyone have good idea to deploy, upgrade it quickly?

Comment: This q is much too vague to get any real answer. If you want a broad discussion of the topic, visit your local bookstore or library.  If you have a specific question, post it here.

Answer (score 2):

You need something that you can reproduce quickly, reliably, with nearly no effort.

This is a huge topic; [infrastructures.org](http://www.infrastructures.org/) has some good guidelines, but as it is a decade old or so, some of the tools of choice have changed. [Puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/) and [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) are popular choices these days.

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Capistrano` https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/Documentation-v2.x
or `Fabric` http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.4.0/index.html
maybe `maven:deploy` http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/

But it really depends on what kind of technology and infrastructure you need to deploy.